Set up Auth0 as a middle layer between a SAML SP and Cognito
I have a Cognito User pool and I want it to act as a SAML IdP against a third party SP. From the research I've made, it looks like Cognito can only act as a SAML SP and a OIDS IdP/SP. I've also seen similar questions here in SO (like this one) where people suggest adding Auth0 as a middle layer that can work as the SAML IdP and use Cognito in the backend to validate the requests.
The thing is this is just casually mentioned as a possibility but I can't find a detailed explanation for this scenario anywhere. Has someone have to deal with this use case and if so can you help with more guidance.
